# How to know with which parameters OpenWRT was built?

Tags: build, openwrt

Suppose I wish to re-build some OpenWRT image with my parameters, like this one: https://downloads.openwrt.org/snapshots/trunk/ar71xx/generic/openwrt-ar71xx-generic-tl-wa901nd-v4-squashfs-factory.bin

How to know, which parameters they used to build this file? Are there any information about this on OpenWRT sites?

Comment: Aren't they built with the default configs (the one that you get after issuing make defconfig)? Or what do you mean by 'parameters'?

Answer (score 0):

on the same directory from the link containing the bin file you can download the [config](https://downloads.openwrt.org/snapshots/trunk/ar71xx/generic/config) file which contains all packages and parameteres that were used to build that image and you can copy the config file to where you are building your image and you will get the same parameters.

Comment: There is only one config. How to separate the settings of my specific bin?